# Give Azure application permissions over API such as "Office SharePoint Online" via PowerShell

Tags: azure, ms-office, office365, azure-active-directory

Is there a way to give Azure Application permissions over Office SharePoint Online API via PowerShell  ?
Manually I would:
1. Enter the Azure AD Admin center.
2. Find/Create the application I want to request permissions for.
3. Click on API Access->"Required Permissions"->"+Add"
[image]

4. "Select API"->"Office SharePoint Online"->"Select"
   [image]
5. Choose "Read and write items in all site collections" -> "Select" -> "Done"
   [image]
6. "Grand Permissions"
   [image]

**If Is not possible can please someone give official link that confirms it?**

Comment: This is an old question. Please refer to this one:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125894/granting-permissions-to-azure-active-direcotry-web-application-automatically?rq=1

Comment: BTW, I think Azure AD powershell cannot achieve all of those steps directly,especially  granting  permissions . Grant  permissions uses "Admin Consent",so,you should use `&prompt=admin_consent` in the auth request directly.

Comment: Wayne, thank you very much for your reply. I already saw examples of achieving similar thing to what i asked with Graph API. But since it requires creating manually Application for Graph API use, and thus the process is not completely automatic, I had to look for different ways such as PowerShell.

Comment: Unfortunately, as I known, there is no way to achieve that for now. You can post your idea in this [Feedback Forum](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory). Azure AD Team will see it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no way to Grant Permissions without someone with Global Administrator role to go to Azure Portal and click Grant Permissions button.
[Reference](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/169401-azure-active-directory/suggestions/31562305-ability-to-grant-permissions-via-api-or-powershell)