# How can i retrive the istances using Azure Management API - permission issue

Tags: azure, permissions, azure-active-directory

When I log in to https://resources.azure.com/ with my credentials, i can retrieve the response from various APIs.

But I want to get the response from my programme, for which i created a App Registration in Active Directory. Get its ClientId, TenantId and Client Screat. 
Now, i am calling Azure Management API using berer token.

But i am getting error as

> The client 'xyzabc' with object id 'xyzabc' does not have
>   authorization to perform action
>   'Microsoft.Resources/subscriptions/resourceGroups/action' over scope
>   '/subscriptions/b51135ea-11ce-4118-8a6f-36dda1bced87'

What do i need to do. Any permissions required to given to the Active Directory App ?

Answer (score 1):

After creating an app, you need to provide access for the Subscription or Resource Group in which your resources resides. You should add the app to the Access Control with Owner or Contributor role. Check [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal#add-a-role-assignment) for more details.

Comment: Do take a moment to consider which role you need though. Owner and Contributor give access to do everything, Owners can modify access permissions too.

Answer (score 0):

> Any permissions required to given to the Active Directory App ?

According to your description, I do not know what the specific API do you want or you want to access to the resource under subscription.

For specific resource API:

If you want to access to Microsoft Graph API, you could go `Registered App > Required Permissions > Microsoft Graph` to click up the permission you want.

For all resource under subscription:

As Arunprabhu said, you could go to `subscription` and `add a role assignment` like Owner and Contributor so that you could access the resource under subscription.

For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/role-based-access-control/role-assignments-portal) and this [one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46125894/granting-permissions-to-azure-active-directory-web-application-automatically).